# C# program that generates html pages - limit image dimensions on page

Tags: c#, html, image, dimensions

I have a C# program that generates a large number of html pages, based on various bits of data and images that I have stored on the file system. The html itself works just fine, but the images can vary greatly in their dimensions. I need a way to ensure that a given image won't exceed a certain size on the page.

The simplest way to accomplish this would be through the html itself... if there was some kind of "maxwidth" or "maxheight" property I could set in the  html, or maybe a way to force the image to fit inside a table cell (if I used something like this, I'd have to be sure that the non-offending dimension would automatically scale with the one that's being reduced). The problem is, I don't know much about this "fine tuning" kind of stuff in html, and it seems to be a tough thing to Google around for (most of the solutions involve some sort of html specialization; I'm just using plain html).

Alternatively, I could determine the width and height of each image at runtime by examining the image in C#, and then setting width/height values in the  html if the image's dimensions exceed a certain value. The problem here is that is seems incredibly inefficient to load an entire image into memory, just to get its dimensions. I would need a way to "peek" at an image and just get its size (it could be bmp, jpg, gif or png).

Any recommendations for either approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the program handling the image size recalculation, there is the option of pushing the burden down to the browser. You could use javascript. This script will "resize" an image down to a max height/width of 200 pixels client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function img_resizer(img) {
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        if (img.offsetWidth) {
            resizeImage(img.offsetWidth, img.offsetHeight)            
        }
        else {
            resizeImage(img.style.pixedWidth, img.style.pixelHeight);
        }
    }

    function resizeImage(width, height) {
        if (width > 200 || height > 200) {
            if (width > height) {
                height = (height / width) * 200;
                width = 200;
            }
            else {
                width = (width / height) * 200;
                height = 200;
            }

            img.style.width = width + 'px';
            img.style.height = height + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<img src="screen.jpg" onload="img_resizer(this)" />
```

I know that works on IE and Firefox, you might have to do some testing on browsers like Safari, Opera, and Chrome. But I don't know, you might just want to bite the bullet and let the program take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for that code sample; that might be the way to go if I can handle it in Html!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [width and height property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp) to the `<img>` tag. If you only specify one, the browser will resize in that dimension and keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: My understanding of his requirements (and some assumptions) mean that this would potentially make some small images larger. He did not say all images were too large, which means that there will likely be some small images and this would probably have some undesirable effects.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem. I need to preserve each image's aspect ratio, too.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has the `max-width` and `max-height` properties. They're supported by the newest versions of all popular browsers.

Comment: This will lose the image's aspect ratio, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying (and a couple assumptions, such as you will work with a single image more than once), it seems like caching an image's dimensions in memory would be one thing to do to increase efficiency here. Doing it this way, then you can intelligently set the dimensions in HTML or CSS.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123838/get-the-resolution-of-a-jpeg-image-using-c-and-the-net-environment) for instructions on how to obtain the resolution (if you don't already know this - unfortunately I know of no way to do this without loading the entire image). I would encourage you to keep that image variable in a very small-scoped area and dispose it ASAP.

I would discourage you from ignorantly using CSS's `max-width` and `max-height` properties as you'll lose your aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback! If it's only adding about 10 seconds to my one-time build process, I might just "bite the bullet" and read in the whole bitmap to get the dimensions. I'd love to be able to just scan the image's header information, but it's going to be different for each file type and I really don't know if I want to spend that much time researching/coding one aspect of a hobby project! :)

Comment: What I ended up doing is reading in the entire bitmap, but "caching" each image's dimensions, file size and date modified to a separate file. On subsequent runs, I can reuse those cached dimensions unless the image's file size or date modified value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no accounting for the amount of copy and pasters out there eh! I also wanted to know this and all I saw were endless examples of scaling width OR height.. who would want the other overflowing?!

- Resize width AND height without the need for a loop
- Doesn't exceed the images original dimensions
- Uses maths that works properly i.e width/aspect for height, and height*aspect for width so images are actually scaled properly up and down :/

//////////////

```
private void ResizeImage(Image img, double maxWidth, double maxHeight)
{
    double srcWidth = img.Source.Width;
    double srcHeight = img.Source.Height;

    double resizeWidth = srcWidth;
    double resizeHeight = srcHeight;

    double aspect = resizeWidth / resizeHeight;

    if (resizeWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        resizeWidth = maxWidth;
        resizeHeight = resizeWidth / aspect;
    }
    if (resizeHeight > maxHeight)
    {
        aspect = resizeWidth / resizeHeight;
        resizeHeight = maxHeight;
        resizeWidth = resizeHeight * aspect;
    }

    img.Width = resizeWidth;
    img.Height = resizeHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set only one of properties: `width` OR `height`(not both or it won't work) of `<img>` element, image will keep aspect ratio, and other value that you didn't set will auto adjust.