# Getting the resolution of an image

Tags: c#, image, webclient, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the resolution of a jpeg image using C# and the .NET Environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123838/get-the-resolution-of-a-jpeg-image-using-c-sharp-and-the-net-environment)

In a batch image downloader I am coding, I use a WebClient (DownloadFile) to save images from given urls. Is there an easy way to get the resolution of these images? If the WebClient cannot, how can i get the resolution after the file is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the image after downloading it from the WebClient, you can use the following:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"image.png");
Console.WriteLine(img.Width + "x" + img.Height);
```

This will give you the width x height of the image, for example, 1920x1080.

Answer (score 2):

To get the DPI use the following:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
image.HorizontalResolution;
```

For other things such as height, width, and size, view [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123838/get-the-resolution-of-a-jpeg-image-using-c-sharp-and-the-net-environment) which has many good answers, (including mine :D ).